# Точка вместо запятой в DataGridView с типом данных Decimal в ячейках

Tags: c#, datagridview, vb.net

При работе в DataGridView данные с типом Decimal отображаются с запятой, можно ли настроить проект или DataGridView, так что бы он работал с точками?

> P.S. Не меняя при этом национальные настройки операционной системы.

Comment: настройки операционной стсиемы менять не обязательно, вы можете поменять [настрйоки потока (Thread)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.currentculture?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Вообще, обратите внимание на поддержку [глобализации и локализации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/globalization-localization/) в своих приложениях. Тема обширная, да...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов.

Во-первых, можно задать новую культуру для текущего потока. Делается это так:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

Здесь выбрана культура, у которой используется точка в качестве десятичного разделителя. При этом, естественно, будет использованы настройки этой культуры для всех типов данных: дата-время, валюта, проценты и прочее.

Возможно, вас устроит универсальная инвариантная культура:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
```

Если же нужна конкретная культура, но лишь с одной изменённой настройкой, то:

```
var myCulture = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");
myCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = myCulture;
```

---

Во-вторых, можно задать настройки формата или культуру только для одного компонента. См. [FormatProvider](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.formatprovider?view=netframework-4.7.2).

```
dataGridView.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = myCulture;
```

В примере меняются настройки определённой колонки в гриде. Культуру, естественно, можно выбрать любую, как в примерах выше.

Также обратите внимание на свойство [Format](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.format?view=netframework-4.7.2). Оно позволяет, например, гибко задавать настройки вывода даты-времени: скажем, только месяц показать из типа DateTime. Для decimal оно особо неприменимо.